# PHP header() function making a entry in error log

Tags: php, http-response-codes

I am making an API.

There I have to show error handling. When any request is not fetched or it is not present in DB or any other error, then the error should be accompanied by the `json_encode` string and HTTP error code should be present in response headers.

As PHP 5.3 does not have `http_response_code` i used a custom made function as written on [PHP documentation page's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) first comment.

The problem is that when I execute this function like `http_response_code(405)` , instead of giving response code in headers, it is making an entry in php error log.

`header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed')` is called from inside the function given above, which makes a PHP error log entry.

Why does this happen? and Why is HTTP response code not obtained in headers when i am making the API call using POSTMAN

**EDIT**

**Error as seen in Error LOG**

> [Tue Jul 14 23:40:07 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning: file_get_contents(localhost/APICall_2.php?ip=127.0.0.1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed\r\n in API_2.php on line 31

Comment: What is the error in the log?

Comment: [Tue Jul 14 23:40:07 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://localhost/APICall_2.php?ip=127.0.0.1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed\r\n in API_2.php on line 31

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: To me that it like you're making the request with PHP (to PHP), getting the right header, and having the request fail.

Comment: my request starts to fetch result when I remove `header()` function . So my request is not failing. I passed the wrong parameters to check my error handling and i shud return error with proper response codes.

Comment: How are you calling your API then? Because the error in the log seems quite correct...

Comment: I am making a API call using postman on link `localhost/somthing.php`. I am giving request parameters as the POST call. when post call is made the `somthing.php` redirects to another file `redirectfile.php` where when encountered any errors it calls a function `http_response_code(405)` . This function call `header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed')` before returning other condition. I am not getting return values. Even if i place echo calls before and after the `header()` function, nothing is echoed

Comment: You should not need to redirect responses in an API. Im Also not sure as why you try to use ´file_Get_contents´ switch your code by replacing that with proper ´curl´ requests

Comment: i cannot use cURL , because i am just modifying an API, i cannot change the workflow.

Comment: The error message is not about `header()` it is about a failed `file_get_contents()` call that triggers an warning that later causes the `header()` to fail. 

Wrap the file_get_contents() in a try/catch or file_exists() ...

Comment: @powtac , as i start to debug and comment out `header()` , the API starts to work. So i assume that problem is with `header()`.

Comment: @Prashant add `if (!headers_sent()) { ...` around your header() call!

Answer (score 0):

Remember response_code is set on the server-side and *must be set* before any body text is sent.  The server access.log will record the 405 but no text.

If ANY bytes are allowed into the output buffer before setting the response_code, the error.log will say so.  You might also configure your php.ini to create a php_error.log file to assist debugging.

windows:
   error_log = c:\apache\apache2.4\logs\php_errors.log

linux
   error_log = /apache/apache2.4/logs/php_errors.log